# Lua match start from the end

Tags: lua, openresty, lua-patterns

I am trying to extract url with match.
I'm trying to find the filename after the "/" character.
But url is always variable so i have to start from end

`123`, `123.py`, `123.dat`

```
url://xxxxx/yyyyy/123
url://xxxxx/yyyyy/123.py
url://xxxxx/yyyyy/123.dat
```

I tried `url:match("^.+(%..+)$")` but I can't access files that don't start with a `.`.

Comment: Why not use `url:gsub(".*/", "")` if you need `123`, `123.py`, `123.dat`?

Comment: yes needed 123, 123.py, 123.dat

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I didn't think it would be that simple. great answer! Thank you.

Comment: I posted the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74132450/3832970) below also providing the solution to find directories, as you asked in a now deleted comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```lua
url:gsub(".*/", "")
```

The pattern matches

- `.*` - zero or more chars as many as possible
- `/` - a `/` char.

To find the directory, you can use

```lua
url:gsub("/[^/]*$", "")
```

Here,

- `/` - a `/` char
- `[^/]*` - zero or more chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the alternative using `match`:

```lua
url:match"[^/]+$"
```

Explanation: Match one or more non-slash characters anchored to the end of string `$`.

This will also match just a filename like `foo.bar` without any slashes. If you want to force slashes to precede your filename, use `/(.-)$` instead.